# writeToFile atomically returns NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
NSString *errorStr = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dict
                                                               format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                     errorDescription:&errorStr];
if (errorStr) {
    // Darn.
    NSLog(@"saving dictionary error %@", errorStr);
} else {
    // [plistData writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
    // (ankit): Changing this to NO for speed.
    success = [plistData writeToFile:file atomically:NO];
}
```

however this returns NO, for the following dictionary:

```
  {
    entries = (
                {
            author = "Jada Wong";
            cellIdentifier = default;
            date = "2012-10-15 02:22:41 +0000";
            domain = Readability;
            feedUrl = "readability://feed";
            imagesAreOnPulsesubscriber = 0;
            order = 0;
            summary = "";
            templateUrl = "default_template.html";
            title = "We\U2019re Going To Try Out Dolce & Gabbana\U2019s Beauty Look This Weekend";
            url = "http://www.styleite.com/media/styledish-10122012/";
        }
    );
}
```

but it works for the following dict:

```
{
    entries =     (
                {
            author = "Colleen Taylor";
            cellIdentifier = default;
            date = "2012-10-15 01:00:05 +0000";
            domain = TechCrunch;
            domainUrl = "http://techcrunch.com";
            feedUrl = "http:/asdasdm/TechCrunch";
            images =             (
                "http://asdshot-2012-10-14-at-5-20-43-pm.png"
            );
            imagesAreOnPulsesubscriber = 1;
            lastUpdated = 1350263095;
            order = 0;
            shortLink = "http://bete.me/s/ej2Tg";
            summary = "Bonobos, the men's clothing company, has gained lots of ground since it was founded in 2007 for its presence on the web as a mostly pure e-commerce p...";
            templateUrl = "default_template.html";
            title = "Inside Bonobos\U2019 New Palo Alto Digs, Where The Startup Known For E-Commerce Is Investing In Bricks & Mortar";
            url = "http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/14/bonobos-palo-alto-mike-hart/";
        }
    );
}
```

Any idea why? It worked for different dictionary 
The file path I am writing to is:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/4B60A704-BE00-4160-BFB4-AD89187FADD1/Library/Caches/StoryCache/readability:  feed
```

The error I got is:

```
"The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0xb41580 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/4B60A704-BE00-4160-BFB4-AD89187FADD1/Library/Caches/StoryCache/readability:  feed, NSUnderlyingError=0xbb8930 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Is a directory"}
```

Comment: `NSData` does not care what the data is so it is not a data dependancy. Try: `writeToFile:options:error:` and check the error.

Comment: @Zaph I am writing a NSDictionary

Comment: No, you are writing `NSData`: `NSData *plistData`. The dictionary was serialized into an `NSData`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `writeToFile:options:error:` instead of `writeToFile:atomically:` so you can log the error code.

```
NSError *error;
success = [plistData writeToFile:file options:0 error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"writeToFile failed with error %@", error);
}
```

#### UPDATE

Based on the error you pasted into your question, I guess you already have a directory named `/var/mobile/Applications/4B60A704-BE00-4160-BFB4-AD89187FADD1/Library/Caches/StoryCache/readability:  feed`.  You cannot overwrite a directory with a file.  You need to rename or delete the directory first.  You can use `-[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:]` to delete a directory and all of its contents recursively.

Comment: hmm..for some reason changing in the file path to /var/mobile/Applications/4B60A704-BE00-4160-BFB4-AD89187FADD1/Library/Caches/StoryCache/jesus worked.. any idea?

Comment: Because the file path was invalid?

Comment: @adit Getting the error message as Rob suggests will tell you what the problem was.

Comment: @adit Uh... the power of christ compelled it? You might be too young to get that reference to *The Exorcist*.  Anyway, get the error object and log it.  If you can't figure out the problem from the error log, paste it into your question so we can look at it.

Comment: I copy pasted the error message on my question, it's saying that it's a directory

Comment: NSLog the file path each write and then figure out why the path is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally wrote NSURL.absoluteString as the argument to writeToFile:. Make sure you do NSURL.path not NSURL.asboluteString!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is "" and NSNull value of Dictionary is not allowed to save to file.  In your case :"summary = "";" so, writetofail return NO.